# UITableView: hide header from empty section

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, tableview

i have a UITableView, that displays expenses from a current month (see screenshot):

My problem is with the header for empty sections. is there any way to hide them?
The data is loaded from coredata.

this is the code that generates the header title:

TitleForHeader

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
    return nil;
} else {

NSDate *today = [NSDate date ];
int todayInt = [dataHandler getDayNumber:today].intValue;

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-(todayInt-section-1)*60*60*24)];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]]];    
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return formattedDateString;}

}
```

ViewForHeader

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
    return nil;
} else {

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 312, 30)];
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 9, 312, 20)];
    UIView *top = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 312, 5)];
    UIView *bottom = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 312, 1)];

    [top setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [bottom setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    [title setText:[expenseTable.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section]];
    [title setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    UIFont *fontName = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin-Bold" size:15.0];
    [title setFont:fontName];


    [headerView addSubview:title];
    [headerView addSubview:top];
    [headerView addSubview:bottom];

    return headerView;

}

}
```

heightForHeader

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSLog(@"Height: %d",[tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0);
if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section == 0]) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 30;
}
}
```

numberOfRowsInSection

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

int rows = 0;
for (Expense* exp in [dataHandler allMonthExpenses]) {
    if ([exp day].intValue == section) {
        rows++;
    }
}

return rows;
}
```

[image]
sebastian

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What if in – `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` you `return nil` if the section count is 0.

**EDIT** :
You can use `numberOfRowsInSection` for obtaining the number of elements in the section.

**EDIT**: 
Probably you should return nil also in `titleForHeaderInSection` if `numberOfRowsInSection` is 0.

**EDIT**: 
Did you implement the following method?

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

**EDIT** : **Swift 3** example

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        if self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section) > 0 {
            return "Title example for section 1"
        }
    case 1:
        if self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section) > 0 {
            return "Title example for section 2"
        }
    default:
        return nil // when return nil no header will be shown
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: sadly it does not work.. i updated the question with new code & a new screenshot.

Comment: no error. just finished editing the question. now the new code is in and the new screenshot.

Comment: by the way, did you implement numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: yes of course - otherwise i would not have any filled sections =)
but for the sake of completion i added the function as well =)

Comment: every time that you do a comparation, you close with .... ==0]), is that ok?...i will use ...]==0)

Comment: damn - sometimes i guess its best to stop working after some time ^^ 
that was of course an error, but it shifts the problem and doesnt solve it. now it makes a destinction between empty & filled sections. but the header is not gone. it now uses the standard header for zero-sections. (screenshot added in question).

Comment: added the updated code & a new screenshot. now i have the default header with a nil titlelable but the height doesnt go to 0 :/

Comment: and what if you check the size of the section header in the nib?..maybe if you use 0 you get a better result..since you are setting it in code.

Comment: YES! it works :D 
you are my hero. found a last faulty comparison. thanks a million times for fighting through my long question =)

Comment: FYI: What makes this scary for me is that adding this line will break things: `- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{return [super tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];}` this is the sign of Apple trying to be too clever

Comment: This is an old question now, but `return nil;` in `titleForHeaderInSection` is sufficient for me (after checking `count > 0` for that section of course)

Answer (score 138):

You have to set `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` to 0 for the appropriate sections. This is something which changed fairly recently and got me in a couple places. From `UITableViewDelegate` it says...

> Prior to iOS 5.0, table views would automatically resize the heights
>   of headers to 0 for sections where tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
>   returned a nil view. In iOS 5.0 and later, you must return the actual
>   height for each section header in this method.

So you'll have to do something like

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        // whatever height you'd want for a real section header
    }
}
```

Comment: sadly it does not work.. i updated the question with new code & a new screenshot.

Comment: Static tables are a bit different. This code is for custom table header views, not just a `title`. If you are setting a `title` you will need to return `nil` for the method call `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` when appropriate. If you are using custom header views you must be overriding  `viewForHeaderInSection`. If you are doing that, this code should work. If not, I would need more information to help with the issue.

Comment: awesome... thanks a lot. earlier i was returning a blank `UIView` like this:     `else`
    `{`
       `vw = [[UIView alloc]init];`
       `[vw setHidden:YES];`
    `}`

Comment: i used viewforheader in section + above code and worked perfectely in ios 6 & even in lower version. thnnxx buddyy

Comment: Worked for me - I am on ios6

Comment: It seems that if your table view is the first child of a navigation view, there's a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20517881/3279

Comment: OK, but can someone explain why this doesn't work then? `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0`

Comment: @turingtested did you verify that you're returning nil in `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`?

Answer (score 55):

In my strange situation I have to return:

> ﻿viewForHeaderInSection -> nil
>
> ﻿  viewForFooterInSection -> nil **(don't forget about footer!)**
>
> ﻿heightForHeaderInSection -> **0.01  (not zero!)**
>
> ﻿  heightForFooterInSection -> 0.01

only in this case empty sections disappear completely

Comment: I did it just by setting headerHeight to 0.01.

Comment: iOS 8.4 I could still see the text using 0.01, but 0.0 worked a charm     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        
        if sectionedTableData[section].count == 0 {
            return CGFloat(0.0)
        }
        return CGFloat(40.0)
    }

Comment: This works for me perfectly. Unfortunately I couldn't found this anywhere else. Thanks dude.

Comment: Even in iOS 12.1, you still have to set the height to ```0.01```.... iOS has some strange bugs.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the method [`-[UITableViewDelegate tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:). Especially the note that accompanies its documentation:

> Prior to iOS 5.0, table views would automatically resize the heights
>   of headers to 0 for sections where `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`
>   returned a `nil` view. In iOS 5.0 and later, you must return the actual
>   height for each section header in this method.

Comment: thanks so mch guys - ill update you in a couple of hours and will accept and upvote whatever worked best :-)

Comment: sadly it does not work.. i updated the question with new code & a new screenshot.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but I'd like to add to it. I prefer the approach of setting the `titleHeader` to nil over altering the `heightForHeaderInSection` to 0 as it can cause problems with `indexPath` being +1 from where is should be due to the header still being there but hidden.

So with that said and building on [DBD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737976/287954) you can set the `titleForHeaderInSection:` to nil for sections with no rows in it like so:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        // return your normal return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In 2015 using iOS 8 and Xcode 6, the following worked for me:

```
/* Return the title for each section if and only if the row count for each section is not 0. */

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }else{

    // here you want to return the title or whatever string you want to return for the section you want to display

    return (SomeObject*)someobjectArray[section].title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be the proper way, It will animate correctly & works clean... as Apple intended...

**Provide appropriate info to the tableView delegate**

When no items in section, Return 0.0f in:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

..Also return nil for:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

**Do appropriate data removal for tableView**

1. Call `[tableView beginUpdates];`
2. Remove items from your dataSource, keeping track of where elements got removed..
3. Call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` with the indexPaths of the cells you removed.
4. if your datasource has no items in it (Here you would end up with just the header). Call `reloadSections:` to reload that section. This will trigger the correct animation and hide/slide/fade the header.
5. Finally call `[tableView endUpdates];` to finish the update..

Comment: Thanks for the tip on reloadSections: :-)
Still cant get anything to work for me with iOS11. Bit annoying :/

Comment: Why do we have to call ```reloadSections```? I noticed that if I don't call it, my table view headers overlap (until I scroll, then the correct header is shown).

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2

Set the heightForHeaderInSection to Zero and if you've a custom section view, set it to nil for sections without cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return height_DefaultSection
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        return tableView.dataSource?.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section) == 0 ? nil: headerView(tableView: tableView, section: section)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm doing this:

(kinda silly that this isn't the default behavior)

This is for if you're using auto sizing section headers, which it doesn't seem like the other answers are using, but I was.

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if let headerView = self.tableView(tableView, viewForHeaderInSection: section) {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```