# Remove section from tableview if rowsInSection = 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have several Sections in my UITableView which sometimes can have 0 rows in it. How can i remove section header if the numberOfRowsInSection is equal to 0?

Here is my code for the sections:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 22)];
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 22)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *string =[[theLeagueArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"league"];
    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 22)];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[theLeagueArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"img"]]];
    [view addSubview:imgView];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:13/255.0f green:78/255.0f blue:102/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737616/uitableview-hide-header-from-empty-section

Comment: put your code for number of rows in section here

Comment: you can count number of section with UITableViewDataSource - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView; and use reload tableview after any change in data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the reference documentation for [tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a) and make it return 0 when you need to hide the section header (also return nil in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` for less total calculations).

Also if you target iOS 7 you can use the new `tableView:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:` for even more optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Try `deleteSections:withRowAnimation:` method. This will remove it from the view, with an optional animation, without affecting your backing data. (You should, however, update the data anyway so that the section doesn't reappear.)

Please check [UITableView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // If array count 0
        if([[workoutarray objectAtIndex:section] count]==0)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        else {


        }
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     // If array count 0
    if([[workoutarray objectAtIndex:section] count]==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 25;
        }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the right way to do it is perform `deleteSections:withRowAnimation:` on your table view and do not forget to update data source appropriately.

But you also can return `UIView` with 0.1 height (it's kinda hack), so it will be invisible for user in this case. To update section perform `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` method.
It will look like this:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
        return [[UIView alloc] init];
    }
... 
}
```