# How to remove the empty section header in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having a UITableView in that I am having three title headers.**problem is:** when my title header value become empty means that header should not show in the table view. I have tried many method its not helped for me. can anyone help me please.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [reverseOrder1 objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return 60;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 75)];
UILabel *headerTitile =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, -5, tableView.bounds.size.width-20, 75)];
headerTitile.text = [reverseOrder1 objectAtIndex:section];

headerTitile.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerTitile.TextAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[headerView addSubview:headerTitile];
headerTitile.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0f];

headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:48/255.0f green:119/255.0f blue:21/255.0f alpha:1];

return headerView;

}
```

Comment: posiable duplicate [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737616/uitableview-hide-header-from-empty-section) . please search before you ask something

Comment: How many sections do you have in your table?

Comment: @AbhishekNath 3 section bro

Comment: @huy nghia i have tried this link its not helped me

Comment: [reverseOrder1 objectAtIndex:section] is NSString ? you want to remove header when header title nil? try set viewForHeaderInSection: return nil heightForHeaderInSection: = 0 when [reverseOrder1 objectAtIndex:section]  nil

Comment: I find I have similar problem. Except I've set my header view to nil AND height to 0 for empty sections. Still doesn't work somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
     {

    if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section == 0]) 
    {
        return 0;
    } 
    else
     {
        return 60;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ravi's answer, make sure you set the section height property of table view to 0 in storyboard.

Comment: It forces at least a value of 1